# How to isolate both Vcc and gnd?

Tags: mosfet, ground, isolation, vcc, digital-isolator

There are three designs of complementary switches, which means that when the button is closed only one of configurations conducts the current and activates the circuit and the other circuit will remain inactive. On the other hand, this action will be reversed when the button is not closed.

The purpose of these designs is to isolate both VCC and GND. They are not intended to work at high frequencies. Assume that these switches are on/off switches which are intended to connect or disconnect both the VCC and GND of each circuit from the main VCC and GND of the board.

10K resistors are pull up or pull down resistors which prevent the gate of the MOSFET from floating.  The 1K resistors are gate resistors which prevent high currents damaging the MOSFET.

Which design is better for this purpose?

If there is a better circuit for this purpose, could you please provide the schematic?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: fig1 won't work...wrong FET types.  The rest seem reasonable.

Comment: Define what you mean by "isolate".  There will be some small leakage through the FETs, so they are not isolated like an air gap from a relay.

Comment: None of these are what I'd call isolated, as there's always the body diode connecting them even if the FET were somehow able to provide perfect isolation.

Comment: 1) Instead of me explaining what is wrong with many of these circuits (like the top MOSFET conducting while the bottom one is **not** conducting), I suggest to put these circuits in a simulator (like LTSpice) and see what happens. 2) realize that disconnecting GND and VCC of a circuit can result in issues, especially if that circuit has a connection to other circuits that are not powered down. Can you explain **WHY** the circuit needs to be isolated (which as explained in other comments, it actually is not).

Comment: When cutting all of the supply rails, you should first cut the positive rail, then cut the GND. In all the figures shown, I don't see anything to perform this priority. So neither is best or better than any other.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I don't see your concern. Are you sure you are interpreting the circuits correctly?  I think in all cases the top and bottom MOSFETs conduct at the same time.

Comment: *I think in all cases the top and bottom MOSFETs conduct at the same time* OK, in for figure 1 I was assuming you used a PMOS to VCC and an NMOS to GND. But that's not the case. So indeed both will conduct **however** Q1 will not fully conduct, it will work as a "source follower" so Q1 will have a large \$V_{DS}\$. It is not a good way to use an NMOS as a high side switch. You would need to make the gate voltage higher than VCC for Q1 to fully conduct. The same applies for PMOS Q4.

Comment: And you still have not explained **WHY** this would be needed and what you're trying to achieve with this. Note that I've seen and designed a lot of circuits in my life and **no one** does what you show here.

Comment: @Aaron
Yeah, the first figure is not a good configuration . Let's take the first configuration. As you know the N-channel MOSFET works as a switch in common source mode so the bottom MOSFET works properly. However, the top one is in common drain mode and it doesn't act as a switch appropriately. This problem has been solved in the second and third figure.
The current leakage isn't really important.

Comment: @Hearth
Simply, MOSFETs act as a resistor. You can find some of their characteristics like R on and R off in their datasheets. So we must expect a little leakage. But I don't get your point about the body diode. In all of the figures the body diode has been biased reversed. Do you mean that the current leakage is due to body diode?

Comment: @elec "isolation" means that there is no current flow between the two points, regardless of direction. So two things connected by a diode are not isolated.

Comment: @elec Isolation is a *safety* (of equipment, operator, or other) consideration first and foremost, and therefore must take into consideration fault conditions that would never occur in normal operating conditions.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie
See, there are two circuits in each figure, which are intended to powered on and off. Each circuit has an output and there is only one pin of micro controller to use. So both outputs go to that pin. In this situation we need to power off one of them completely in order to use the other one. If only VCC or GND of the first circuit is disconnected the output of the other circuit, which is working may interfere with the first one.
Also there is no possibility to use dip switch for each VCC and GND or other solutions like analog switch chip because it takes up a lot of space.

Comment: @RohatKılıç
What is the reason of this priority?
If it is really critical we can manage it by choosing appropriate value for resistor of gate and selecting the MOSFETs according to their characteristics. So we can decrease the capacitance of the MOSFET's gate that switches the VCC and on the other hand, increase the capacitance of the MOSFET's gate that switches the GND.
In this situation, the VCC will be cut faster than GND.

Comment: @Hearth
OK, I see. Thanks.

Comment: *So both outputs go to that pin. In this situation we need to power off one of them completely in order to use the other one.* I would solve that in a different way, I would use some **analog switches** (like HEF4066) to switch between the two. I still think you're overcomplicating your circuit and that the same can be achieved in a much simpler, more elegant and more robust way.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie
Yeah 4066 is a solution.
But as I mentioned before it takes up a lot of space in comparison to some sot23 MOSFETs and resistors. It also costs more.

Comment: The 4066 is **ancient**, I have no doubt that similar but smaller (smaller SMD package) ICs exist. Use digikey, mouser etc to find them.